# How to access function from every controller in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Hi friends hi have this function in one controller , how can i access it from every other controller ?pls help

```
public function click_add($ads_id){
    //some statement here
    redirect($ads_site['url']);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few possibilities:

- Define a [helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html)
- Create a parent controller class from which all other controllers in your application extend
- Create a [library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)
- Use [ModularExtensions](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home) to allow calling one controller inside another

It all depends on what exactly the function should do. If it shouldn't access the model, then you could go for the first three options. Otherwise I'd suggest the latter two.

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be to create your [own library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html).